# Why this (dead simple) ruby regex behaves like this?

Tags: ruby, regex

Why `"whatever".gsub(/.*/, "bien")` outputs "bienbien" instead of just "bien"?

I'm completely lost here :S Anyone could point me in the right direction?

Comment: because * repeats the previous token zero or more times, try `+` instead of `*`

Comment: seems like ruby's gsub function is defined in another way.

Comment: `"whatever".gsub(/.*/).to_a` => `["whatev", ""]`. @AvinashRaj has the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see what's happening using a block:

```
>> 'foo'.sub(/.*/) { |m| p m; 'bar' }
"foo"
=> "bar"
>> 'foo'.gsub(/.*/) { |m| p m; 'bar' }
"foo"
""
=> "barbar"
>> 'foo'.gsub(/^.*/) { |m| p m; 'bar' }
"foo"
=> "bar"
>> 'foo'.gsub(/^.*$/) { |m| p m; 'bar' }
"foo"
=> "bar"
>> 'foo'.gsub(/.*$/) { |m| p m; 'bar' }
"foo"
""
=> "barbar"
>> 'foo'.gsub(/.+/) { |m| p m; 'bar' }
"foo"
=> "bar"
```

Put another way, gsub will continue matching, and matches an empty string at the very end a line. (And that is arguably a bug.)

Comment: That empty string matching doesn't make any sense if you ask me. Since I'm implementing a way to support aggregations based on regex patterns, I'll have to describe this weird behavior as a gotcha in our final user docs. Any further clarification would be hugely appreciated though.